# Can I use 'glutton' for someone playing video games a lot?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

One of the meaning of glutton is "a person with great capacity for enduring or doing something" which is very close to an informal word in my native language which means *eater* e.g. we say *he's a video game/driving/computer eater* which means he does these activities a lot and often it implies that he's good at them, too. Can I use glutton to make this concept in English?

> He's a glutton for videogames/driving/computers.

If not, any suggestions? (I did some search online but I frequently came across *glutton for punishment* that's why I thought it might be wrong to use glutton in this way)

**Edit**: Let me expand the scope to verbs and expressions. I'm looking for a way to express this concept in a concise and idiomatic fashion.

Comment: You can try looking up "fanatic" and "maniac" and seeing if they fit for what you want to say, but it's important to note that these do not necessarily imply that the person is "good" at these activities as the word in your native language would. These two only mean that the person is crazy about the activities.

Comment: +1 for maniac, which I agree does not explicitly state someone is good but (IMO) tends to imply it (because someone who's a maniac for something is unlikely to be bad at it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People (at least those who don't play them) would understand you if you said "He's a glutton for video games".

Similar colloquial ways to express "excessive consumption" or "excessive use":

He overdoes it with the video games.

He's addicted to video games.

He's married to that game console.

He's a game-aholic.

He's a video-game zombie.

He won't let go of that game controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, "He pwns at video games."

This does not mean that he plays a lot of video games, but it's strongly implied as "to pwn" at something, you'd probably do it a lot.

This is also an excellent translation as it is also current and modern-day slang as is the word you are trying to translate from your native language.

Meanwhile, "to pwn" at something means [to be really good at the thing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pwn).

And "pwn" is versatile as you could say also use it to say that someone beat you in a game, "You pwned me!", you could also use it in real life, "He totally pwns you in basketball," and you could also use it just by itself, "Pwned!"

[image: Pwned!]

Comment: And how is it pronounced? Andit cms rather context-specific. Is there a more general way to say that so i could extend it to _driving, computers_ for example?

Comment: @Yuri, personally, I pronounce it like "coned," but with a "p," "poned." But if you go to the Wikipedia link for "[Pwn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwn)," you'll see that pronunciation varies because the word had started out written, not spoken. In the meantime, it came about as a typo of "owned," which is why I pronounce it to rhyme with "coned" and "owned."

Comment: And the person originally had wanted to say "owned" because we sometimes say we "owned" someone when we dominate them in a game or competition.

Comment: I have to say, this doesn't mean at all the same thing as the OP's question to me.  To *pwn* is simply about being very good at something, and it has a very different implication from "glutton" or that the subject just does it a lot.

Comment: @stangdon, I agree and had said as much in my answer. I had also upvoted Cardinal's suggestion for "buff." In the meantime, I had been focusing on the second aspect of the OP's request that the word in the OP's native language is a slang term and "often implies that he's good at them, too."

Comment: @Yuri, sorry, I just saw your edit. You can say, "He pwns at programming," "He pwns at racing." Without more context, I'm not sure what you mean by "driving" and by "computers."

Comment: @Yuri, and if you look at the UrbanDictionary website, second definition, you'll see "pwned" used in non-video-game contexts: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pwn.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities:

**He's a great one for video games.**  To [*be a great one for X*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-a-great-one-for-sth) means to be a big fan of X, or a frequent and enthusiastic doer of X.

**He's a video gaming maniac** or **He's a maniac for video games**.  [*Maniac*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/maniac) literally means "someone who has a [mania](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mania)", but is used informally to mean "someone with a very strong enthusiasm".